# how to generate random numbers of specific digits?

Tags: java, android, random, numbers

I want to create a string of random numbers, where starting digit should be in the range from 1-9, which selects only single number, after that 2 random digits should be there from range 10-99.
Means from range 1-10 let's say 1 is selected, and for 2nd and 3rd digit range should be between 10-99.
Like 111, 245...
second digit should not be a single digit.

Tried Code:

```
            int random1 = new Random().nextInt((9 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            int random2 = new Random().nextInt((99 - 10) + 1) + 10;
            textSelectedFileName.setText(String.valueOf(random1+random2));
```

Comment: I think it needs to be something like this: Random r = new Random(); int random1 = r.nextInt(9); int random2 = r.nextInt(89)+10; You can look at the Docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random#nextInt(int)

Comment: NextInt that takes a single argument is the "Max" value it can return, Meaning, in random1 you are basically saying the minimum value you can get is 0, the maximum is 10 and then you add 1 to that, so it can generate any number between 0 and 11

Comment: You should not be adding the integers before creating the String. You should create both Strings from each of your random `int`s first and then concatenate these Strings to create your three-digit String.

Comment: While the for random2 you are saying the max value is 100, so it can generate "100" also, and you can get something like 11100

Comment: Also, as @maloomeister mentions, adding the numbers will treat them as integers. Meaning, if random1 is 9 and random2 is 40, you won't get 940 like you intended but you'll get 49 You can either convert them separately as strings and combine them which I'm not really recommending or you can simply change the addition to: (random1*100)+random2

Comment: Random r = new Random(); int random1 = r.nextInt(9); int random2 = r.nextInt(89)+10; In this code random2 is also generating single digit @DanBaruch

Comment: That's not really possible, the +10 there is to make sure that even if the random generates 0, it will be +10. Hang on, I'll post a full answer, maybe it's not showing properly in this comments section

Comment: Guys, you are thinking way to complicated - why not just `100 + r.nextInt(900)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate your randoms like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
int ran1 = r.nextInt(9)+1; // Will give values from 1-9
int ran2 = r.nextInt(90)+10; // Will give values from 10-99
```

You then create your string like this:
Opt 1 (Less recommended):

```
String s1 = String.valueOf(ran1);
String s2 = String.valueOf(ran2);
textSelectedFileName.setText(s1+s2);
```

Opt 2:

```
textSelectedFileName.setText(String.valueOf((ran1*100)+ran2));
```

Comment: Opt2 is generating single digit sometimes, other wise Opt1 is working correctly.

Comment: This will produce codes with initial digit 0..8; other two digits 10..98

Comment: Edited according to Gyro suggestion, might fix it

Comment: This will still fail the first requirement that the initial digit must not be zero

Comment: Guess I missed the non-zero part, anyway, fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();

int randomNum = rand.nextInt((maximumvalue - minmumvalue) + 1) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Math.random`

```
int b = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)
```

for example  `(int)(Math.random()*(99-10+1)+10) //Generate random int value from 10 to 99`